# TLE whileusing hashmap but not while using map[256]={}

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am doing [this code](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/smallest-window-in-a-string-containing-all-the-characters-of-another-string-1587115621/1#) and when I am trying to solve this using a hashmap like `unordered_map<char,int> m` I am getting `TLE` (Time Limit exceeded), but whenever I am using the hashamp like this `map[256]={0}` then my code runs fine. Why is this happening? Isn't the unordered_map works the same way as an array does with O(1) access time complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unordered_map` is asymptotically O(1) but in real time it is often much slower than an array.
This is for several reasons. Hash functions take some time to compute which are not needed for an array and you need to handle hash collisions which can be very expensive in comparison. An array is contiguous memory which reduces Cache misses by a lot.

The main takeaway is that the asymptotic O notation is an approximation to performance but is only works for big inputs and does not care about constants. So one O(1) can be 100 times faster than an other O(1).

The other takeaway is that you should always prefer arrays or vectors over other data structures if you do not have a good reason to do otherwise.
A hash map would be good if your Key-Space would be to big for an array for example `unordered_map<long long, int>`.